# DevExpress ASPxComboBox not working in IE11

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, devexpress, visual-studio-2005

I am using DevExpress ASPxComboBox in my project. I Internet explorer 11, ASPxComboBox doens't show any options/list but when i add compatibility view to my page, it works fine.

I think this is because of IE version, I am using devExpress version 7.

Any help would be highly appreciated !!

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know the DevExpress v7.x.x does not support IE11 (and it is quite strange to expect that components developed more than 7 years ago (2007) would correctly support all the latest browsers).
This browser is supported starting from the 12.2.5 and 13.1.8 versions. Please refer to [DevExpress ASP.NET components - Browser versions support history](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/KA18683) for more information.
For now I suggest that update your components to resolve this issue.

Related issue: [ASPxComboBox' dropdown is not shown if it is placed in the ASPxPopupControl and the site is running in IE10/IE11 with CompatibilityMode set to IE7](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/B251570)

Comment: I have updated my component but i am facing with another issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24445686/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-devexpress-version-11-1-in-asp-netvb

Comment: that issue is also fixed now.

Comment: I have devExpress 11 now and DevExpress drop down is working fine in IE11 but not in chrome and firefox.