# Could not load file or assembly DevExpress version 11.1 in asp.net(vb)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, devexpress, visual-studio-2005, asp.net-2.0

I am working on project which is build on 2.0 framework of .net
We were using devExpress version 7 before but the some controls of devExpress 7 doesn't supports modern browsers. So i installed and included devExpress version 11 assemblies.

I copy/pasted assembly files of version 2011 into Bin folder of my project.
I added reference in web.config file

In web.config, I have now

```
<add assembly="DevExpress.Data.v11.1, Version=11.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
<add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.v11.1, Version=11.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
<add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.v11.1, Version=11.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
<add assembly="DevExpress.Web.v11.1, Version=11.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/></assemblies>
```

In my asp file i have :

```
<%@ Register Assembly="DevExpress.Web.v11.1, Version=11.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9b171c9fd64da1d1"
    Namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxDataView" TagPrefix="dxdv" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.v11.1, Version=11.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9b171c9fd64da1d1"
    Namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView" TagPrefix="dxwgv" %>    


<%@ Register Assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.v11.1, Version=11.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9b171c9fd64da1d1"
    Namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors" TagPrefix="dxe" %>    

<%@ Register Assembly="DevExpress.Web.v11.1, Version=11.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9b171c9fd64da1d1"
    Namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxTabControl" TagPrefix="dxtc" %>
```

Well i dont know about `Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9b171c9fd64da1d1"`  I just copy/pasted it from previous assemblies register tag

When i run my project, I am getting following error :

```
Could not load file or assembly 'DevExpress.Web.v11.1, Version=11.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9b171c9fd64da1d1' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

Please assist me on this and tell me why the system is not able to find assembly files.

Thanks..
Anjum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assembly's public key token is another for 11.1.  So, to resolve this problem you need to either remove this information from your source code or update it to the correct value.  I suggest that you use project converter to upgrade your project to this version.  Usually, it is located in "{DevExpress folder}\Components\Tools\DXperience\" folder.

Comment: Yes, already did this and it is working fine now. I have accepted your answer though :)

Answer (score 0):

I used project converter to convert my project from devExpress 7 to 11 and it works fine.
Project converter comes with installation package of devExpress 11.

I hope this will help others facing with same issues.

Thanks..
Anjum